# Shouldn't merged questions be tidied and closed as duplicates before merging?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, locked-posts, merged-questions

Today I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm) with the following message:

> Is there no way to make the duplicate banner appear when merging? At present, there's no sign that this is a dupe until after the question body; can we unlock, close as dupe, and relock? Culling some of the fluff from the question body (or at least the hideous signature) would be nice too, since nobody can do so once the question is locked again.

I got declined with this message:

> Please refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com to suggest changes to the banner appearance. It works as designed for now.

But aren't both of the remedies I suggested in my flag available to a moderator? This is the first time I've ever seen a merged question that didn't have a duplicate banner at the top, and after using [a query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/226427/find-merged-questions) to find merged questions, I see that most of them do - see, for instance, [Javascript src starts with //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975684/javascript-src-starts-with) or [What is wrong with using SELECT * FROM sometable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972023/what-is-wrong-with-using-select-from-sometable) or [Why make anything internal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016115/why-make-anything-internal) or [Working password encyption methods for user password managment needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989126/working-password-encyption-methods-for-user-password-managment-needed) or [Determing Python version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016157/determing-python-version-at-runtime) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323839/work-programming-vs-spare-time-programming. The only example I can find that *doesn't* have a duplicate banner is [How can I implement a dispatch table using Perl objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917151/how-can-i-implement-a-dispatch-table-using-perl-objects).

Merge stubs are meant to be signposts; it seems that leaving them without a banner at the top and in a state of ugliness and gratuitous length makes them less effective at that role. Am I misguided, or was this a good flag that should've been acted upon?

Comment: FYI, merge stubs redirect anonymous users to the duplicate target.

Comment: *Pops open an incognito window and tests...* So they do! Thanks, @Gothdo. There are of course plenty of non-anonymous users, though, so I don't think it makes this a non-issue!

Comment: IIRC mods can't unlock merged posts unless they clear the merge history.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed the question.

In the future, the moderator involved will know to close as a duplicate *first* before merging.

There are a number of pitfalls involved with merging questions that new mods have to learn; it's not the most user-friendly tool in the bag.

Comment: If merging implies 'duplicated of", shouldn't it trigger the "closing as duplicate"?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338935/automatically-close-questions-as-duplicates-when-merging-them