# Automatically close questions as duplicates when merging them

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

Currently, *most* merged questions are marked as duplicates, but not all. When moderators don't mark a question as a duplicate before merging it, it doesn't get `[duplicate]` in its title and doesn't have the **Possible Duplicate:** banner at the top. This makes it much less obvious when arriving from Google that the question is a duplicate, which delays the reader finding a link to the target question (and risks a visitor seeing that the question is closed and leaving before ever noticing the duplicate link).

Duplicate questions are supposed, at least in part, to act as signposts; merged questions *have no other remaining purpose* but to be signposts. Having a link at the *top* of the question helps them serve that purpose. To see what I mean, consider the experience of a user arriving at each of the two pages below:

### Obvious duplicate:

[image: Obvious duplicate]

### Also a duplicate, but non-obvious because it was merged without closure:

[image: Non-obvious duplicate]

While mods can (and should!) always explicitly close questions as duplicates before merging them, this clearly shouldn't be necessary - the system ought to be able to do it automatically. Worse, [apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338915/shouldnt-merged-questions-be-tidied-and-closed-as-duplicates-before-merging#comment417743_338915) there is no easy mechanism for a mod to fix this once a post has been merged.

Can we make merging automatically cause duplicate closure, and retroactively mark all merged questions as duplicates?

Comment: I believe users arriving from Google will never actually see the interstitial stub question, so this is probably an issue concerning only a few users. Having said that, that merge banner *is* rather non-obvious and could do with a redesign. There shouldn't be two different mechanisms (duplicate & merge) necessary to deal with this problem.

Comment: @deceze *anonymous* users won't see the stub, but as far as I know they're visible to anyone who's signed in. There are plenty of users with accounts out there (around 6 million of us, in fact!). We matter too! And we use Google!

Comment: The system doesn't allow moderators to do a question merge without the source being closed as a duplicate of the target...

Comment: @JonClements oh. So do you know what causes some merged questions to have a duplicate banner and others not to, then? Is this in fact a bug?

Comment: @JonClements the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37452463/revisions) on the second screenshotted post disagrees with you. By the looks of it, the question was closed, but not as a duplicate. Either the revision history is wrong, or you are - I have no way to tell which!

Comment: @MarkAmery On one of the rare occasions I've gone to merge a question and clicked proceed it's come back and said it can't do it as the question isn't closed as a duplicate - so I've always been forced to close first... I'm looking at the timelines and trying to see if there's anything obviously different between those two questions you mention. However, I wouldn't put it past failing memory and me being wrong :p

Comment: The displayed close reason is the one chosen by the **majority** of voters. Perhaps there was at least one duplicate vote and the system saw "closed" + "duplicate vote" and allowed the merge to proceed.

Comment: Actually, the merge just requires that one of the questions is closed. It doesn't matter what the close reason was, just that it is, actually, you know, closed. And, I have it on good authority that you can merge an open question into a closed one - which would leave both questions right royally rogered. So you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 14):

I agree this would be a nice convenience.

It would also be handy if the system automatically posted comments under every moved answer alerting the author that they may need to tweak their wording slightly to avoid incongruity under the new heading.

But for now, it's not particularly onerous to do these things manually; merges are fairly rare, and additional cleanup (comments and so on) nearly always needs to be done manually anyway.

#### Related: [Should merged questions be closed as exact duplicate instead of just locking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96469/should-merged-questions-be-closed-as-exact-duplicate-instead-of-just-locking)

Comment: I wonder when someone will make a bot to look for potential merge candidates and start making these kinds of requests on a more regular basis, just so that it becomes common enough that the tooling would warrant being addressed.