# Was this question merge the right thing to do?

Tags: discussion, merged-questions

<sup>(Part 4 of a [multi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911/can-the-mods-agree-on-how-we-should-mass-flag-comments) [part](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338915/shouldnt-merged-questions-be-tidied-and-closed-as-duplicates-before-merging) [series](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338935/automatically-close-questions-as-duplicates-when-merging-them) of posts all triggered by this one question.)</sup>

Two days ago deceze merged [FCM Vs GCM? Why we need to migrate from GCM to FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm) into [Migration from GCM to FCM needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311188/migration-from-gcm-to-fcm-needed). I don't think the merge (at least as it was done) was a good thing, and I think it makes an interesting case study in when and how questions should be merged.

I'll list my issues what with was done here:

- The question should've been closed as a duplicate and the asker's ugly, space-hogging signature block edited out before merging. Failure to do this pushed the only duplicate banner that's present on the original question off-screen, making it [a less helpful signpost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338935/1709587) than it would otherwise have been.
- The previously tidy question at [Migration from GCM to FCM needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37311188/1709587) got a mass of crap comments dumped upon it (unfortunately I didn't screenshot these and have since gotten them all deleted), including a bunch from the asker of the merged question lamenting that he couldn't upvote the answers he received due to his lack of rep.

  These comments were noise and warranted deletion even on their original post, but migrating them onto another post, where they clearly made no sense, was even worse; it made the author of the comments look like an imbecile who had randomly decided to post his questions about how to upvote in comments on some random stranger's question, and was rude to to the author of the target question (who suddenly, if he cares about the tidiness of his question, has to spend time flagging a bunch of comments that could've been tidied away *before* the merge). I think it's reasonable to expect moderators to always read the comments on a question and clean them up if needed before doing a merge; that didn't happen here.
- The merge direction was wrong. Answers to the target question would all have made sense on the source question, but [the highest-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453051/1709587) from the source question *doesn't* quite make sense on the target question. For one thing, [prior to me editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37453051/revisions), it started with "Welcome to Stack Overflow", which makes little sense now that it's answering a question from  [a user who joined in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751581/patrick). But secondly, the format of the answer consists of quoting the individual small questions that together made up the source question (complete with their grammar and spelling errors) and answering them one by one.

  Now that the source question is no longer anywhere to be seen, the answerer looks like an idiot. *What are all of these questions in quote blocks?*, a naive reader will wonder. It looks like either he's plagiarized some answer from a related question, or has written these questions (complete with grammar and spelling errors) himself. Only somebody aware of the merge can see the reality; to everyone else, the answerer has been made to look stupid.

  This isn't okay! Yes, looking carefully at all of the answers to make sure that something like this won't happen is several minutes of work, but I don't think it's an unreasonable burden. Merging questions is a drastic (and, I believe, irreversible) action; moderators should be taking the time and care to ensure that moving other people's words into a different context isn't going to make them look like fools. That hasn't been achieved here.

  I think I can tidy this up acceptably, by fixing the English throughout the answer and by putting a small disclaimer at the top of it noting that the answer was originally given in response to another post that posed the 5 questions listed. But this could've been avoided by picking the right merge direction in the first place. Yes, the source question was awfully written, but editing it to be less awful would've been less work than editing the answer to make sense in its new home will be.

Am I right to think that this merge was done badly, or do others think this was okay?

Comment: I've gone ahead and heavily edited [the highest-upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37453051/1709587) to make it fit in in its new home.

Comment: Kudos for jumping on that cleanup! The awful forum-style mess of the merged question makes me sympathetic to the merge direction. (That signature block alone is making my edit finger itch painfully.)

Comment: I think the issue here is that you assume that a merge should be the final step, and that everything should be clean and tidy once the merge is complete. In the uncertain world we live in, there is always bound to be some clean up afterwards. A mod may be able to discern enough to know that it is a good merge candidate based on a flag, but it isn't their job to tidy it all up afterwards. That is the community's job. Should there be better coordination on the two actions? Probably.